# How to get values of selected Listbox item into Listview

Tags: c#, sql, listview, stored-procedures, listbox

I am developing a C# Windows Form Application.

Now i am trying to select value from Listbox and load corresponding value in List view using the stored procedure.

[image]

And this is my Stored Procedure:
[image]

Can any one help please?

Thanks

Comment: If you are this early in development, *seriously* consider doing this application using WPF instead.  It is incredibly better suited to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write an event on selection changed of listbox.then you can get the value of selected value.

```
  private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox l = sender as ListBox;
        var selectedvalue = l.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

then you have to pass the orderid to your SP and SP will return the data of that order id and bind that data to ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if I interpret your question correctly you are asking for How to call a stored procedure using C#?

This is rather easy to do first you need to initialize an [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) and then you need to issue an [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Put that together and you can make calls to a SQL database.

Here is an example for how to make a simple storedprocedure call.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

You can read more about it here. [How to execute a stored procedure (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)